# FileWrite not creating new file Android Studio, getting 'java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.py: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)'

Tags: java, python, android, runtime, filenotfoundexception

so i've been trying to run a simple python script in java using the runtime method. It worked well outside of android studio, but in Andorid studio I keet getting this error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.py: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)'`.

I know that this isn't the most effective way to run a python script through Java, but please help me out. I don't know what permissions to change in order for new script to be written.

Heres my full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView resultstv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultsTV);
        Button solvebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.solvebtn);
        final EditText enterWordTv =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.enterWordET);

        solvebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                resultstv.setText(anagram(getEnterWordTv(enterWordTv)).toString());
            }
        });
    }


    public String getEnterWordTv(EditText inputFU) {
        String finWord = inputFU.getText().toString();
        return(finWord);
    }

    static ArrayList<String> anagram(Int num){
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            String mainPrg = "import sys\nprint(sys.argv[1])";
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("AnagremSOlver.py"));
            out.write(mainPrg);
            out.close();
            String number = num;
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 AnagremSOlver.py " + number);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String ret;
            while ((ret = in.readLine()) != null){
                results.add(ret);
            }
            System.out.println(results);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return(results);
    }



}
```

Other answers from other places have told me to update the permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` by adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` but having added it, I still get the same problem.

Comment: I think you should supply a full path for the file to theFileWriter. As where would you think it would be stored? Or is it the input stream reader that causes the exception? You should know and tell us.

Comment: And you use an Android Q/10 device?

Comment: If you tell `told me to update the permissions in AndroidManifest.xml but it doesn't do anything `then we don't know what you have done. Pretty unclear.

Comment: @blackapps hey, i updated the question. I am new to android development and don't know where the file would need to be stored. I think the problem is that the FileWriter is unable to create a file (since the project is readonly??) and there the error occurs. I am using Android 11.

Comment: But even if you are new you could find out which statement causes the exception. Just by removing some statements and so. So please find out and tell.

Comment: Ok, so after looking at it again, I find that their is no new file being created by the `FileWriter`. `BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("AnagremSOlver.py"));` this line is where the problem is, as this line is somehow not able to create a new file.

Comment: Can be. But i did not ask if the file could be created or not but which statement caused the FileNotFoundException. Please answer to the point.

Comment: This is what my logcat gives me `26.677 7263-7263/com.example.anagramsolver I/System.out: java.io.FileNotFoundException: AnaSolver.py: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)`. Its not really specific to which statement causes it. But I think its this statement `out.write(mainPrg);`, as there is no file created and therefore this line cannot find the file to write the code into. I'm sorry, I don't know how to be more specific. In the app a button is clicked which launches the `anagram()` function, there is an `EditText` which is where the user input is given.

Comment: Remove all code after ou.close(). (comment it) Then try again. Then you willl know/ Further  AnaSolver.py is not in your code. There i see twice "AnagremSOlver.py". So what is this?

Comment: And in the subject you say that it is produced by running the script. I do not understand why you cannot find the statement that causes it.

Comment: @blackapps ok i got it figured out after commenting out. The error occurs here `BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("AnaSolver.py"));`. I was experimenting with the name of the python file to see if it would change something, that's why the name is different here.

Comment: The name is no problem. But you should use a full path. File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "AnaSolver.py");  ..... new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath())..... And change the subject of your post now you know that that was not the problem.

Comment: @blackapps thank you. your solution works.!